# How to get next row element in list without iterating

Tags: python, csv

In this script I am writing I need to look for a certain value, once I receive it I need to grab the next value without iterating to it so I can modify the one I am currently at. Is there a sort of next method that I can use? I need to do this because the data assumes that whenever "certain value appears" the next row has the corrected value. 
The data I am using would look something like this (this is not the actual data):

```
11:59    59       
00:00    certain value
12:00    0
```

Here is an example of the code

```
for row in csv_reader:
    if row[1] == "certain value": 
        row[0] == next row[0] #how do I do this a nextitem in list method
```

Comment: Maybe treating the csv as a list of rows and iterating with `range(len(list_of_rows))`

Answer (score 1):

> look for a certain value, once I receive it I need to grab the next value without iterating to it so I can modify the one I am currently at.

If you currently have a value `v` of list `lst`, you can get its index by calling `lst.index(v)`. For the next value, you can call `lst[lst.index(v)+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next row in your for loop by:

```
next_row = next(csv_reader)
```

Meaning for the for loop:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  # used other data with comma delimiter
  for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
    if row[1] == "certain value":
      next_row = next(csv_reader)  # this provides the next row
      # Do something with next row
```

**Explanation**

This works since a for loop is equivalent to:

```
it = iter(csv_reader) # calls csv_reader.__iter__
while True:
    try:
        row = next(it)
        # Do something with row
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

We have injected an additional next into the while loop where we have *Do something*.

Namely, is equivalent to:

```
it = iter(csv_reader) # calls csv_reader.__iter__
while True:
    try:
        row = next(it)
        if row[1] == "certain value":
            next_row = next(csv_reader)
            # Do something with next row
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

**One Caveat**

Rather than just

```
next_row = next(csv_reader)
```

You may check for StopIteration with

```
try:
   next_row = next(csv_reader)
   # Do something with row
except StopIteration:
        break
```

Unless you're certain there is always a following row.

Comment: I think the OP does not want to just jump to the next row, but to look at the next row while saying on the current row,

Comment: @BobMcCormick--he can have the current row as row, and the next_row = next(csv_reader).  But, he has to advance the iterator (i.e. iterators don't have a 'peep' method).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, iterators only provide "next".  There is no look-ahead or "go back".

You probably need to do this in 2 passes.  First, use the csv.reader to iterate over the file and make a list of rows.  Then iterate over the list with

```
# Pass 1, get data into list
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
for row in csv_reader:
    row_list.append(row)
# Pass 2, iterate over the list 
for index, row in zip(range(len(row_list)), row_list:
   if row[1] == 'certain_value' and index < len(row_list)-1:
      row[0] = row_list[index+1][0]
```